# Why does the code return the same 5 random numbers every time

Tags: c#, random

When I call the GenerateLotteryNumber method 5 times it returns the same 5 numbers:

```
    Lottery myLottery = new Lottery();
    String temp;
    temp = myLottery.GenerateLotteryNumber().ToString();
    txtLotteryNumbers.Text = temp;  

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        txtLotteryNumbers.Text += ", " + myLottery.GenerateLotteryNumber().ToString();
    }


    public class Lottery
    {
        public int GenerateLotteryNumber()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int randomValue = rnd.Next(1, 41);
            return (randomValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious which .NET platform this is (like is it iOS or one of the less common ones)? Just tried to reproduce and can't.  The dup answer is right, it's more "proper" not to make a new `Random` for each "dice roll" but that alone shouldn't normally cause this in modern .NET.

Comment: All versions of the .NET Framework exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @EmperorEto I thought the default would be a random seed if no parameter is provided to the constructor.

Comment: @nicomp: The behavior is explained in the first Remarks section on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-8.0

Comment: @MichaelLiu yes .NET **Framework** but is that what the OP is using?

Comment: "In **.NET Core**, the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator, so the previously described limitation does not apply. Different Random objects created in close succession produce different sets of random numbers in .NET Core."

Comment: So @nicomp which .NET version are you using? If it's Core (5+) then this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I agree with not creating a new random with each call. I use a static for my "dice roller" and it behaves as "required".

Comment: All - as of .NET 6, `Random.Shared` is the only thing that ever needs to be used and should ever be used. That dup question is very old and has a ton of noise answers and comments that don't apply to modern .NET. It would've been nice to have a more recent Q&A on this, IMO.

Comment: For a lottery you'd use a **cryptographically secure random number generator**. The default `Random` implementations of most PL's are simple, fast and not very secure. Use [this for .NET 9 / Core 3 and upwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getint32?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-randomnumbergenerator-getint32(system-int32)) and note that official lotteries etc. may have legal requirements for e.g. a TRNG.